# How to make date selection using javascript fromat?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, date

[image]In my PHP project I'm using 3 comboboxes to select Year, month and date. But I can't format that 3 values to save as a date in database in 2013-10-01 type. Given below is my code to select date.

```
  <p>
      <label class="floated" for="dtb_yr"><b>Date of Birth :</b></label>

            <select name="dtb_yr">
                <option value="2013" />2013
                <option value="2014" />2014
                <option value="2015" />2015
                <option value="2016" />2016
                <option value="2017" />2017
                <option value="2018" />2018
                <option value="2019" />2019
                <option value="2020" />2020
                <option value="2021" />2021
                <option value="2022" />2022

            </select>

            <select name="dtb_mon">
                <option value="january" />January
                <option value="february" />February
                <option value="March" />March
                <option value="Apirl" />Apirl
                <option value="May" />May
                <option value="June" />June
                <option value="July" />July
                <option value="August" />August
                <option value="September" />September
                <option value="October" />October
                <option value="November" />November
                <option value="December" />December
            </select>

            <select name="dtb_day">
                <option value="01" />01
                <option value="02" />02
                <option value="03" />03
                <option value="04" />04
                <option value="05" />05
                <option value="06" />06
                <option value="07" />07
                <option value="08" />08
                <option value="09" />09
                <option value="10" />10
                <option value="11" />11
                <option value="12" />12
                <option value="13" />13
                <option value="14" />14
                <option value="15" />15
                <option value="16" />16
                <option value="17" />17
                <option value="18" />18
                <option value="19" />19
                <option value="20" />20
                <option value="21" />21
                <option value="22" />22
                <option value="23" />23
                <option value="24" />24
                <option value="25" />25
                <option value="26" />26
                <option value="27" />27
                <option value="28" />28
                <option value="29" />29
                <option value="30" />30
                <option value="31" />31
            </select>
            <br class="clear"/>
        </p>
```

Is there any way to select date and save date in more accuracy way, like given below textfeild?

```
     <p>

            <label class="floated" for="model_no"><b>Model no :</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="model_no" id="model_no" placeholder="Enter Modle No" />
            <br class="clear" />
        </p>
```

Comment: Please post your ajax query. Lets see if any errors

Comment: I do not understand the question. If you change the values of the month select to numbers, you have your date, you just need to add a dash

Comment: use <select name="dtb_mon">
                <option value="1" />January
                <option value="2" />February
.....

Comment: :) I'm so sorry I'm new to PHP. I only have PHP cords which written to save this whole form and HTML/ Java script design. If you can explain me how to find this ajax query I can post them.

Comment: You could use any javascript libraries like jQuery in your project. you can find working demos http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @Dilini You should consider to use some javascript framework that can print you a calendar field instead of use three comboboxes.  Like this one: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @Zahidul Hossein Ripon and what I suppose to do when I'm gona save it.. How I'm gona add those thress year, month, and date value? Sould I take addition of those v3 values to a variable and save it?

Comment: @Dilini check this out:http://jsfiddle.net/2BsKk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery Date picker that you only need to select date and it can be save in specified  format in database.

Add this code in head of your HTML document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 <script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#dtb_yr" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 });
 </script>
```

Add this in your form
in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="dtb_yr" id="dtb_yr" placeholder="Select Date" />
```

Add this code in PHP file
In PHP:

```
 $dtb_yr =  $_POST['dtb_yr'];
```

Comment: { dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' } is the format. You can give any format  inside $( "#dtb_yr" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

Comment: It is giving me yy-mm-dd that is 2013-12-03. Hopefully works for you as well.

Comment: $( "#dtb_yr" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); 
I have updated my answer. Just use it and your issue will be solved.
1. Add code in head
2. Add in HTML form
3. PHP code

Comment: 1. Add javascript code in head of you page. 
2. Update your HTML form 
3. Get date value in PHP. Thas's it. Format is already specified in JS

Comment: <title>Mobile Phone Repairing Records</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <style>
            
   <script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#dtb_yr" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 });
 </script>

Comment: without using script src can I save save those scripts in my projects and call them?

Comment: you can save a script on local machine but src will be required even then to include in your file

Comment: Please remove the style tag infrom of script tag  
<style> <script> $(function(). here remove style tag before script tag. this is the err.

Comment: Yeah I saved http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css this cord. But I don't know what methods should I call? And when I saved other 2 jscripts as css, there are lots of errors.

Comment: please add http:// in front of code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
otehr wise download and save it in your system and give proper path.

Comment: 1. first remove style tag  before <script> tag.

Comment: 2. you have used ../css/... .Is your file outside of this html file path.
first try to use exact paths that I provided.

Comment: please look at the photo I updated. :) your answer is right. :) But still that datepicker is not clear. Can you give me a suggestion here?  Please?

Comment: ok let us go step by step.
1. What is the issue you are facing now?
2. is your css folder inside the mobile folder?

Comment: if css folder is inside mobile folder then use css path like this <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">

Comment: did you fix the issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42729/discussion-between-dilini-and-maz-iqbal)

Answer (score 1):

use Month option like this

```
<select name="dtb_mon">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">Apirl</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
```

after submit your form

```
<?php
$date_string=$_POST['dtb_yr']."-".$_POST['dtb_mon']."-".$_POST['dtb_day'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using 3 different combo boxes to format your date, I think it might be easier to use a single text field with Jquery UI's datepicker. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

For the format you are looking for, you can customize the datepicker's output. The documentation covers this quite well.

If you really want 3 different boxes, Zahidul's answer should work.

**EDIT**

Use this code as a guide:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd mm yy" );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
```

The important part is `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd mm yy" );` where you are formatting the date according to your needs.

Comment: thanks you are being so helpful. I want one date type. dd mm yyyy. can yous show me how to select that..

Comment: See my edit above. Use the `dd mm yy` format to create 08 12 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the values that you get and at the PHP side you can use STR_TO_DATE function of MYSQL.you need a little mapper for having the month number from the text. Then you use this function--->get the output and use it for insertion in your database.check out the article here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
 STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
```

BTW, theres a typo in April.